# .Net приложение не может добавить файлы в системе linux

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-mvc, daemon, systemctl

При запуске через daemon выводит ошибку о том что нету доступа, вопрос, как можно добавить права службе или куда переместить корень приложения чтобы можно было добавить туда изображение?
Но когда запускаю через консоль все нормально функционирует без ошибок
На данный момент приложение находиться в /home/sps2011

```
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       INSERT INTO `Items` (`HighDescription`, `ImgListUrl`, `ImgUrl`, `LowDescription`, `Name`, `Price`, `Pric>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7);
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       SELECT `Id`
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       FROM `Items`
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1 AND `Id` = LAST_INSERT_ID();
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]: info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__item_HighDescription_0='?' (Size = 4000), @__item_LowDescriptio>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       SELECT `i`.`Id`, `i`.`HighDescription`, `i`.`ImgListUrl`, `i`.`ImgUrl`, `i`.`LowDescription`, `i`.`Name`>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       FROM `Items` AS `i`
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       WHERE (`i`.`HighDescription` = @__item_HighDescription_0) AND (`i`.`LowDescription` = @__item_LowDescrip>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       LIMIT 1
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]: fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:       System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/home/sps2011/wwwroot/img/item/62.ico' is denied.
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:        ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:          at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirError)
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:          at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode, Func`4 c>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:          at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access,>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:          at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Fil>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:          at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 b>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:          at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:          at SPF.Controllers.ItemsController.Create(Int32 TypeName, Item item, IFormFile UploadImg) in F:\Repos>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(A>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaite>
Sep 29 11:16:48 sps2011s.sps2011.by dotnet-example[39962]:          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Aw>
```

код в файле запуска

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Linux

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/sps2011/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotner /home/sps2011/SPF.dll
Restart=always

# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGNIT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
#envs
Enviroment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIROMENT=Production
Enviroment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Не приводите код картинкой.

Comment: может забыли chmod?

Comment: А как его прописать в сервисе?

Comment: А через `daemon` от имени кого запускается? Так то конечно проще всего дать права хотя бы на чтение ваших файлов всем пользователям. Но лучше разобраться от кого запускается и права чтобы были только у этого пользователя.

Comment: daemon запускается от root, у меня только root на сервере на данный момен

Comment: `User=www-data` это совершенно очевидно не root

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, изменил с User=www-data на User=root

Comment: Но лучше ничего не запускать от имени root без крайней необходимости

Answer (score 0):

Выдал права пользователю и указал его в запуске daemon

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Linux

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/sps2011/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotner /home/sps2011/SPF.dll
Restart=always

# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGNIT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=(administrator)
#envs
Enviroment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIROMENT=Production
Enviroment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: p.s. а что, у вас в системе существует учётная запись с именем «администратор»? а зачем вы её создали? ну и вообще совет, мягко скажем, не очень умный.